# Behavior of optim function in R

Tags: r, optimization

I have a function of which I want to find a global minima.
It is defined on the support (0,\infty).
I displayed its plot for x in [0.1,5] and I believe it is increasing beyond 5.

[image]

From the plot, it is obvious that its global minima is 1.5.
When I used optim function in R, however, the results highly depend on the initial value.

The initial values and corresponding optim results are as follows.

```
Initial value - optim result
          0.5 - 2.016
          1.0 - 2.853
          1.5 - 1.5
          2.0 - 2.016
          2.5 - 2.565
          3.0 - 3.060
          3.5 - 3.484
```

How can I get a 'correct' result?

Comment: It looks like you have multiple local optima's. Have your tried the simulated annealing option `SANN` for `method`

Comment: could you provide more information including your dataset and what opt function you used? It will be better with reproducible code.

Comment: Could you provide the function you are using?

Comment: That is a strange looking function. I am curious why initial values of 0.5 and 1.0 cannot find the global minimum point.